# How do I test whether my node.js app calls a REST API?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, tdd

I have a React app that is supposed to call an external api. I'd like to write a simple test that tests only whether my react component calls certain API. Something like:

```
it 'should call GET /external/API/', (done) ->
  expect(app).to_call.get('/external/API/').end(done)
```

I use [superagent-mock](https://github.com/M6Web/superagent-mock) to mock the API, but how do I simply test that the app is calling it?

Comment: You should use nock - which overrides your HTTP calls and you can then proceed to make assertions on that scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Sinon test library (or if you're using Chai, the sinon-chai plugin) to spy on the `get()` method